# Where have the PvP vendors gone?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Season 13 PvP gear has been released today, but the player vs player vendors are no longer in the Halls of Legends in Orgimmar.

Have the PvP vendors been moved? If so - where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alliance PvP vendor is in the Valley of the Four Winds, roughly here:

[image]

There is a FP next to it, so if you track that on the minimap should be easy enough to find.  They are inside the tower.

Answer (score 1):

The new PvP vendors are located at Serpent's Shrine, upon the wall between the Vale of Eternal Blossoms and Townlong Steppes:

[image]

The Horde NPCs Lok'nor Bloodfist and Doris Chiltonius sell Honor and Conquest gear respectively:

[image]